# How to organize AngularJS unit tests from multiple projects?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

We have a VS2015 web solution with multiple projects where we use AngularJS. We decided to start writing unit tests for AngularJS code and picked up Jasmine framework. It means .js files with modules are not in one project only and I'm wondering how to centralize the testing.

What to do with .js files from different projects in order to be available for centralized unit testing?

Comment: Tests are with protractor ?